# Bayes classifier using maximum likelihood

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood, posterior

Derive the estimate of the Bayes classifier from m data points $(x_1, y_1), . . . ,(x_m, y_m)$ using Maximum likelihood.

Do so under each of the following assumptions.
$Y ∈ {−1, +1}$, $X ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
$P(Y = +1) = a$, $P(Y = −1) = 1 − a$
$X|Y = −1 ∼ N (μ_−, σ^2_−)$
$X|Y = +1 ∼ N (μ_+, σ^2_+)$

How to approach this problem? Is it to be solved using MAP method?

Answer (score 0):

In Bayes classifier, you choose the class that gives maximum posterior probability/density. I'm not sure what you mean by Bayes classifier using ML. If you use ML, you won't take priors into account. For Bayes classifer, let $c$ be chosen class label for a given sample $x$: $$c=\operatorname{argmax}_c P(Y=c|X=x)=\operatorname{argmax}_c P(X=x|Y=c)P(Y=c)$$
If this is what you call as "MAP method", yes, you'll use it.